# Grouping by status then priority and extracting the earliest start time and latest end time if they exist in different rows

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, how can I group by status, then priority, and take the start time and latest end time if they exist in different rows?

This is how my data looks right now:

[image: Screenshot od current data]

This is what I'd like the data to look like:

[image: Screenshot of required output]

Comment: If you have tried something that is not working please share it with us.

Answer (score 0):

Group them first and let min/max extract the right time like:

```
SELECT id, name, status, priority, min(start) as start, max(end) as end, end-start as 'time difference' 
FROM issues
GROUP BY id,status, priority
```